# htaccess rule index to folder

Tags: .htaccess, rule

does any one knows how to write a proper .htaccess rule

When someone types www.mydomain.com to redirect the visitor to a specific folder www.mydomain.com/foldername

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
...what to write then..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without mod_rewrite. You can use the [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive:

```
Redirect / /foldername
```

Be careful that if you are using a version of Apache older than 2.2.6, relative URLs can not be used and you need to use a complete URL in the same domain as your site instead:

```
Redirect / http://www.mydomain.com/foldername
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what did the trick for me..

first of all..

no other rules are included in htaccess file..

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://wwww.mydomain.com/folder/
```